# Using a loop to get certain elements from Json

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I have a class which contains a method. The method queries everything from a database table and returns the result in json format.

I am then calling that method like so:

```
$consultants = new Consultants();
$consultants->getUsersJson();
```

This returns something like:

> [{"con_id":"1","con_firstname":"Paul","con_lastname":"Bloggs","con_username":"paul@email.com","con_password":"password","con_job_category_id":"0","con_updated_at":"2015-07-08 00:00:00","con_created_at":"2015-07-08 00:00:00"},{"con_id":"2","con_firstname":"Allan","con_lastname":"Bloggs","con_username":"paul@email.com","con_password":"password","con_job_category_id":"0","con_updated_at":"2015-07-08 00:00:00","con_created_at":"2015-07-08 00:00:00"},{"con_id":"3","con_firstname":"Ryan ","con_lastname":"Bloggs","con_username":"ryan@email.com","con_password":"password","con_job_category_id":"0","con_updated_at":"2015-07-08 00:00:00","con_created_at":"2015-07-08 00:00:00"}]

I now need some sort of loop to go through this as I only require `con_firstname`, `con_lastname` and `con_username`. It also needs to look something similar to this:

```
{"data"[{"con_firstname":"Ryan","con_lastname":"Bloggs","con_username":"ryan@email.com"}]}
```

(So that it is all wrapped in "data". Also this is just one, the loop should show all of them.)

Answer (score 0):

Try it, it may fail hardcore:

```
$consultants = new Consultants();
$users = $consultants->getUsersJson();

json_decode($users); 
$users = object_to_array($users); 
$data = array(
            'data'=>array()
           );

foreach ($users as $user){
    $data['data']['con_firstname'] = $user['con_firstname']
}

function object_to_array($data)
{
    if (is_object($data)) {
        $data = get_object_vars($data);
    }
    if (is_array($data)) {
        return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $data);
    }
    else {
        return $data;
    }
 }

json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, just to compensate on Kisaragi's answer, you can use 'json_decode($users,true)' to get an array directly

Comment: Consider adding this as a comment instead.